# setSelectionStyles not immediately affecting Textbox's _textLines.length

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to get the number of lines in a Fabric.js Textbox. The text inside the textbox is inputted by the user, and parts of the text can be formatted to bold using `[b]` and `[/b]`. This text is then formatted using `setSelectionStyles` (changing the fontFamily).

```
for (var i = 0; i < parseResults[1].length; i++) {
  fabricText.setSelectionStyles({fontFamily: "font_SeagullBold"}, parseResults[1][i], parseResults[2][i]);
}
console.log(fabricText._textLines.length);
```

In an example case, the text to be formatted is 8 lines long. Upon being formatted, because of text wrapping, this number will increase to 9. However, `_textLines.length` does not seem to reflect this immediately. Is there a way to "wait" for `setSelectionStyles` to "finish" formatting the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by calling `canvas.add(fabricText)` and `canvas.renderAll()` before getting `_textLines.length`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < parseResults[1].length; i++) {
  fabricText.setSelectionStyles({fontFamily: "font_SeagullBold"}, parseResults[1][i], parseResults[2][i]);
}
canvas.add(fabricText);
canvas.renderAll();
console.log(fabricText._textLines.length);
```